# Get pCloud to backup hidden files

Tags: backup, rsync, pcloud

I've got the pCloud app for backups, but it excludes all hidden files, some of which, like my key chain, I really want to make sure are backed up.

Can I do this with the GUI app?  If not, can I use rsync? Is it possible to run the GUI app **and** use rsync without making two copies of (nearly) everything?

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: You could use *LuckyBackup* from Ubuntu software. It's a GUI version of rsync basically and you can set to include system files and specifically hidden .file types.

Comment: January 7, 2022 - Unfortunately the development of luckybackup is almost frozen. I will not stop supporting this project but please have in mind that this will affect future fixes of known bugs as well as the implementation of new features. https://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely you can use `rsync` to backup to pCloud.
It is actually a basic `rsync` command to do so but there are some nuances.

As for duplicates, if you backup twice, to different locations, then you are going to have two copies of everything, because that's what you did ;-) To avoid duplicate backups, only backup once, or only to the same place.

I've stopped using the pCloud backup facility, although I'm not sure precisely why, I suppose I just get more control from arranging my own backups.

Unfortunately for you, pCloud reserves permissions on it's own `pCloud Backup` remote directory, so you can't run `rsync` to the same location that pCloud sends it's GUI feature backups to. You will either have two backups or you need to stop using pCloud Backup and just `rsync` somewhere else.

Alternatively you can just selectively backup your dot files, and any other "special" files with `rsync` while using pCloud Backup as usual.

### rsync

The Rsync [home page](https://rsync.samba.org/) and [manual](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rsync) [page](https://man.developpez.com/man1/rsync/) provide useful summary, examples, and some additional detail on the options I will recommend.

###### Dry Run

Rsync calls can be dangerous. If you're unused to the specifics you can cause a mess or delete unexpectedly. Use `-n` ("No" option) to do a "dry run" that will list files that *would* have been updated, just to check what will happen when you run it for real next time. I will include `-n` in all the examples below so you can remove it when you're ready.

###### Trailing Slashes

Many regular Linux shell commands function just as well with or without a trailing slash on the end of a directory name. Not `rsync`. Adding a trailing slash makes a difference. When directory path ends in a trailing slash it means "the contents of the directory". Without a trailing slash it refers to "the directory itself" (and therefore the contents as well). When copying command lines be sure to copy paths *exactly* unless you know how you want to modify the targets.

###### Archive Mode

Especially when backing up, Rsync is often used in "archive mode" using the `-a` (for "archive") option, frequently with the "verbose" and "compress" options as well: `-avz`. This may work for you but with cloud storage I often find that permissions are not supported on the remote storage in the same way that they are on the local drive. Attempting to copy permissions fully can mean that `rsync` never finds the remote copies identical, because the permissions are different. This can then result in unnecessary copies and increased bandwidth. I will not use "archive mode" for this reason (although I'm not 100% sure it helps!).

###### Deleting Old Files During Backup

The expected behaviour when backing up mostly includes deleting files from the previous backup, when they've been deleted on your local (master). This can be achieved with Rsync by using the `--delete` option. But such destruction can be a mistake if for some reason your backup is ahead of the local (supposedly master). I will not include the `--delete` option in the following commands but you can add it in when you're ready.

###### Dot Files

The "dot files" (files named with a leading period) are automatically included in `rsync` calls. You do not need to use an `--include` option. Just run the recommended command.

However, you may *not* want to include *all* "dot" files, and certainly not all "dot" directories (such as `.cache`, `.config` and `.local` which can contain many subdirectories and be quite large).

For this reason you will probably want to create a list of home directory "dot" files to exclude. To do this in a file called `.rsync` in your home directory firstly create the file:

```
ls -1a ~ > ~/.rsync
```

Now edit the file so that only the files you want to exclude are left in the list. This file will be referenced by the upcoming commands to make sure those particular files are not backed up.

###### Rsync Command

Here are a list of Rsync commands that achieve slightly different backups, leading up to a command to backup your whole home directory, minus the exclude list.

The following Rsync command should copy the **contents** of your `local/source` directory into the pCloud `destination` directory *without* creating another `source` directory on pCloud:

```
rsync -n -rltvzx --no-p --no-o --no-g local/source/ ~/pCloud/destination
```

So if you're keeping backups on pCloud under directories of the same name as your local then, for instance, to backup your home `Documents` directory, you may want to run:

```
rsync -n -rltvzx --no-p --no-o --no-g ~/Documents/ ~/pCloud/Documents
```

To backup your entire home directory to a `backup` directory on pCloud, except for the exclude list, run:

```
rsync -n -rltvzx --no-p --no-o --no-g --exclude-from=~/.rsync ~/ ~/pCloud/backup
```

Using the usual progress reporting, which reports files transferred; if you re-run it, it should only report directories, once all the files are identical on the remote as they are on your local.

Run without the `-n` when you're convinced you have the right paths for the job.

###### Rsync Options

This is what the Rsync options in those commands are doing:

- `-r`: recursive (copy all subdirectories as well)
- `-l`: copy symlinks as symlinks (don't make additional copies)
- `-t`: preserve modification times
- `-v`: verbose (lists files being transferred)
- `-z`: uses compression on copy (save bandwidth and time)
- `-x`: does not cross file systems (avoid other mounts you may have)

Additionally, the `--no-p` (no permissions), `--no-o` (no ownership) and `--no-g` (no group) options (should) be more permissive about permissions preservation on the remote storage that may only have one owner or group anyway.

`--exclude-from=~/.rsync` names the file that contains a list of all filename patterns to be excluded from the sync.

###### Mixing Clouds

I actually use pCloud and Dropbox at the same time, but I've stopped letting them both access the same directories ;-) However, I think you *can* play with that kind of fire, but you may be *wise* to switch one of them off, especially during heavy transfers. Also be aware that these comprehensive management systems don't necessarily cater to customised use of your environment, such as Linux users are more likely to want. In particular there may be "dot directories" that contain large numbers of files that can delay or possibly mess with your regular use. You may be better off either ensuring no overlap or potentially adding `--exclude` rules to prevent backup of control files from another backup system.